# Change Screensaver font size, Molecule xscreensaver

Tags: linux-mint, screensaver, xscreensaver

I love the Molecule xscreensaver. Is there anyway to change the configuration so that the font of the molecule information is larger? It's located at the top left of the screen and is quite small.Using Mint Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the molecule program (for my OS it is in `/usr/libexec/xscreensaver/molecule`)  with `--help`, and looking at `man molecule` don't provide any obvious way to change this appearance. However, 
a quick look through the strings in the binary of the application shows a typical *X11 resource* for the title font:

```
$ strings /usr/libexec/xscreensaver/molecule | grep -i font
  ...
*titleFont:  -*-helvetica-medium-r-normal-*-*-180-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

So you can run the program with an `-xrm` option to set this resource to a font (and size) of your choice.  Test it with the command

```
/usr/libexec/xscreensaver/molecule -xrm '*titleFont:-*-helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-68-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'
```

(or wherever it is in your OS). 
The number 68 here is the pixel width of the font.  If there is no change and you get an error about no such font, you probably need to install some more standard fonts.

Once happy with the appearance, save the desired font.
Use the `xscreensaver-demo` gui to do this, or more simply edit `~/.xscreensaver` so the line with `GL: molecule -root \n\` is replaced by, for example:

```
GL: molecule -root -xrm '*titleFont:-*-helvetica-bold-r-normal-*-68-*-*-*-*-*-*-*' \n\
```

Note, this is only possible because this program is an old-school native X11 application. Newer programs often use graphical libraries and more complicated methods to set their appearance, to fit in with "the desktop's look and feel".